# DiskLruImageCache avoid erease cache onClose

Tags: android, caching

I'm using the DiskLruImageCache to store Bitmaps into DickCache. Thing is that, everytime that the app closes, It deletes the diskCache folder content. I doesn't happen onPause, just onClose. Any suggestions to avoid that?

thanks